What's Happening in Euclid's Elements Book 10?
Euclid's Elements consists of 13 books, which cover a large swath of mathematics, not just the famous geometry it's known for. I get what's going on in most of the books, but Book X, the longest of them, has always eluded me. I vaguely understand it deals with quadratic irrationals.
What concepts in modern mathematics correspond to the ideas explored in Euclid's Book X? Specifically, in modern language:

What do the definitions like "fifth apotome" or "third binomial" mean?
Could you translate one of the later propositions (for instance, X.92) into modern notation?
Are there any good and clear resources explaining Euclid's Book X in modern notation?


Have you seen David Joyce's discussions?

See D.H. Fowler, An invitation to read Book X of Euclid's Elements (HistMath, 1992)
